# How can I display <div> only on home page via Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I accomplish this via Javascript or jQuery?  New front end developer w/ little to no JS exp.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: `$('#myDiv').show()`...? Even with no experience you should be able to read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Don't use the said tag on any other pages.

Comment: LOL.....................

Comment: Uhm.... I don't even know where to start. We'll need *a lot* more info.. about your website, what is home, what is this <div> .. why is it everywhere.. etc. And of course, you have to actually show us the code you have tried and encountered problems with

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory.  I'll book mark the documentation page you referenced.  Sorry, I know this is a JS 101 question.  It's pretty embarrassing.  I'll get there.  Tx again.

Comment: Homepage URL (I did not build this site, lol):  http://fp37.a2zinc.net/clients/CBA/ICRS2015/Public/MainHall.aspx

Comment: Sorry, the code is here as well:

<div>
<ul class="buttons">
 <li><a href="https://www.expologic.com/registration/dsp_eventstart.cfm?eventID=695" target="_blank"><img src="http://fp37.a2zinc.net/clients/CBA/ICRS2015/Custom/Images/Interface/register-button.png" /></a></li>
 <li><a href="https://intre.org?223" target="_blank"><img src="http://fp37.a2zinc.net/clients/CBA/ICRS2015/Custom/Images/Interface/reserve-button.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: Please add all the asked information to the question itself (there's an "edit" link below the tags).

Comment: Simply need to only display this code below on "only" my home page.  Im using a .NET in-house build CMS.  We use messages and .inc files to display content.  So I put this content in a message, but it will display on every page of the site.  I only...need it to display on the homepage.  Tx.

Comment: Hi @Chris, under your question you should have a button where is says *edit*. Please use that and put the information there instead of in the comments, as comments may be deleted in the future. Another thing would be great if you could show on your website where exactly this div is situated, either by explaining or showing an image and posting the code used here on SO. You can't upload images directly to SO yet but you can link them normally. SO's policy is pretty strict and requires users that ask questions to follow [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.pathname === "yourHomePath") {
  $('#myDiv').show();
} else {
  $('#myDiv').hide();
}
```

But like the others were saying, with more info about the technologies that you're using we might be able to find a better solution for your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to add the code to the original question and I keep getting error messages.  Frustrating.